# Is there a way to handle SSL certificate - issue in Internet Explorer & Edge in Slenium with NUnit

Tags: selenium, ssl, certificate, nunit

I am writing automated tests for Internet Explorer and Edge. After invoking the website, the SSL Certifictae issue appears. Is there a possibilitie, to change the options of the browsers, so that this annoying certificate does not appear annymore?

This does not work (no error, but ssl certificate issue still there)

```
 InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions
                {
                    EnablePersistentHover = false,
                    BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private",
                    EnableNativeEvents = false,
                    EnsureCleanSession = true,
                };
                ieOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptInsecureCertificates,true);
                InternetExplorerDriver internetExplorer = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
```

And when I run the code like this:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOpt(AcceptInsecureCertificates = true}
InternetExplorerDriver ieDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

Then this appears:

> System.InvalidOperationException : No matching capability sets found.
>   Unable to match capability set 0: acceptInsecureCerts was 'true', but the IE driver does not allow bypassing insecure (self-signed) SSL certificates

What can I do?

Comment: It is a [known problem](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4704). If you want to accept arbitrary untrusted certificates there is no workaround except using a different browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
 if(driver.Url.Contains("https"))
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");